# How to use tensorflow library with sagemaker preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, preprocessor

I want to use TensorFlow for preprocessing in sagemaker pipelines.

But, I haven't been able to find a way to use it.

Right now, I'm using this library for preprocessing:

```
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

framework_version = "0.23-1"

sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(
    framework_version=framework_version,
    instance_type=processing_instance_type,
    instance_count=processing_instance_count,
    base_job_name="abcd",
    role=role,
)
```

**Now, I need to use TensorFlow in preprocessing but the python module cant import TensorFlow.**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So there's no TensorFlow Processor module, the list of available processing modules are in the following [doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html#data-pre-processing-and-model-evaluation-with-scikit-learn) and can be seen at the bottom of the page.

You can use a [Processor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.Processor) and [ScriptProcessor](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ScriptProcessor) class and pass in your TF preprocessing as a script with a requirements.txt for the necessary modules.

I work for AWS and my opinions are my own.